# No available plugins for templates

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm following the [Django-CMS introductory tutorial](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/tutorial.html) and have got everything working up to the point where I can run my server and access the admin interface.

However, when I add a page, I cannot select any plugin, it just says `No Plugins present. Add a plugin to this placeholder-slot.`

In my settings.py file I have:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'cms',
    'mptt',
    'menus',
    'south',
    'sekizai',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ok so I found that adding 'cms.plugins.text' for example shows up. But why don't the others? Is it because they are not plugins designed to be used in the page design view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins in django-cms are being discovered by looking for `cms_plugins` module inside each of INSTALLED_APPS. Plugins shipped with the CMS are stored in several [separate modules](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/tree/develop/cms/plugins) so you should add a line for each of your desired plugins:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'cms.plugins.flash',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    ...  
)
```